# How to partially mock a custom react hook with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking

I would like to mock some of my custom React hook return value with Jest.
Here is an example of what i'm trying to do :

```
export default function useSongPlayer() {
  const playSongA = () => {...}
  const playSongB = () => {...}
  const playSongC = () => {...}

  return {
    playSongA,
    playSongB,
    playSongC,
  }
}
```

Now in my test, I would like to mock only `playSongA` and keep the other functions real implementations. I tried several approachs, including someting with `jest.requireActual('hooks/useSongPlayer')` but it seems that `playSongA` is successfully mocked while the others are just undefined.

With something like this, i'm pretty sure to achieve what i want

```
export function playSongA() {...}

export function playSongB() {...}

export function playSongC() {...}
```

The problem seems to be the module I try to mock is a function, and I want to partially mock the result of this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you create a mock that returns the original, but also intercepts the function calls and replaces one of the values.

You can do this without a `Proxy`, but I choose to demonstrate that as it's the most complete method to intercept any use of the actual hook.

**`hooks/__mocks__/useSongPlayer.js`**

```js
// Get the actual hook
const useSongPlayer = jest.requireActual('hooks/useSongPlayer');

// Proxy the original hook so everything passes through except our mocked function call
const proxiedUseSongPlayer = new Proxy(useSongPlayer, {
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    const realResult = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
    return {
      // Return the result of the real function
      ...realResult,
      // Override a single function with a mocked version
      playSongA: jest.fn(),
    };
  }
});

export default proxiedUseSongPlayer;
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. I did not try it yet but, just for curiosity, how would you do without a Proxy ?

Comment: If you didn't use a proxy, you would have to intercept the function call by replacing the function with one of your own and pass all of the arguments along to the original. I use a proxy here because I don't want an upgrade of React, for instance, to break your tests because of some edge case.